# How to get this data permission configuration on Oracle?

Tags: oracle

I'm writing an application and I would like to know whether is it possible to get this data permission configuration on the Database side (Oracle) not the application side.

It's basically related to some tables that have to store historical data that can not be edited the day after they were typed...

Table : X

Fields :

- WhatEver as varchar2
- MyDate as DateTime

For each row, if (Current Date = MyDate), editing is allowed. Otherwise, No.

Is that possible please ? Am I required to use Oracle Label Security ?

I'm looking for something that can be managed as Access Rights (Grant/Revoke...) The usage would be that the administrator can Create, Grant or Revoke such a permission to a user or a role.

Thanks.

Comment: You could put a before update trigger on the table which would reject the update if your condition wasn't met...

Comment: Thank you. I though about it but I'm looking for something that can be managed as Access Rights (Grant/Revoke...) The usage would be that administrator can Create, Grant or Revoke such a permission to a user or a role

Comment: Practically, some users will be allowed to do such thing but not others...

Comment: What's the permission? You haven't stated a permission in the question. Is it that some users should be able to update the table, and some shouldn't? Or that some users should be able to update any row, and others only those > 1 day old? or something else? Either way, you'll still need a trigger to check the data each time such an operation is performed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A row level trigger should do the trick.

```
create or replace trigger my_trigger
  before update on my_table
  for each row
begin
   -- Only compare the date part  (trunc removes the time)
   if trunc(:old.mydate)!=trunc(sysdate)
   then raise_application_error(-20000,'Updates only allowed on the day of entry');
   end if;
end;
```

Of course, entries added just before midnight have a very short edit time.
Also, you should somehow disable the possibility to update the mydate field. Some extra lines in the trigger will take care of that.

Comment: Thank you. I though about it but I'm looking for something that can be managed as Access Rights (Grant/Revoke...) The usage would be that administrator can Create, Grant or Revoke such a permission to a user or a role.

Comment: You can work that into the trigger. Test if user has some role and allow/dissallow the update.